# Segmentation fault: unable to fix the problem

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I'm new to C++, and I'm trying to write a project that interacts through command line. Right now, whenever I run my main (which is the executable), I always receive a segmentation fault error when the main program finished.

---

**Edit comment:**
I'm told by tutor to use as little as C++ features such as vectors or strings ... I'm also very new to C++, so i'm trying to utilize as many basic C functions as I can.

---

I'm
My main function looks like this:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    cout << "starting mvote..." << endl;
    int run_flag = 1;
    char* actionBuffer = (char*)malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
    char* action = (char*)malloc(16 * sizeof(char));
    char* readPtr;
    char exit[4] = { 'e','x','i','t' };

    //parse command line argumentand get the filename
    char* filename = argv[2];
    cout << filename;
    FILE* fp;
    char line[64];

    //from here, I'm opening the file and read it by lines
    fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        cout << "file not exists";
        return -1;
    }

    while (fgets(line, 64, fp) != NULL) {
        cout << line << "\n";
    }
    fclose(fp);


    while (run_flag == 1) {


        cout << "what do you want?\n " << endl;
        cin.getline(actionBuffer, 1024);

        if (strcmp(actionBuffer, exit) == 0) {
            cout << "bye!";

            run_flag = 0;
            break;
        }
        //if not exit, Look for the space in the input
        readPtr = strchr(actionBuffer, ' ');


        int size = readPtr - actionBuffer;
        //extract the operation

        strncpy(action, actionBuffer, size);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            cout << "operation:" << action[i];
        }


        // depend on the operation specified before the first empty space

        run_flag = 0;
    }
    free(actionBuffer);
    free(action);
    return 0;


}
```

---

**Description**:

I first try to open up a csv file which lies in the same folder as main, and I read the file line by line. Then, I just implement a simple command where you can type exit and quit the program.
I allocate two memory, **actionBuffer** and **action**, which are used to hold command

---

**Problem**: a segmentation fault [core dumped] always exists when I type exit and hit enter, and then the process finished.

---

Research: So I learned that segmentation fault is due to accessing a memory that does not belongs to me. But where in my program am I trying to access such a memory?

---

Any advice is appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: That's a pretty odd combination of C and C++. Stick to C++.

Comment: first rule of C++, don't talk about C++. second rule: get a good book or tutorial.

Comment: I'll tell you right now, that since the string `exit` only holds 4 characters, you cannot safely use it with the function `strcmp` which expects a null-terminated string.  Not to mention it's strange to use a variable with the same name as a standard function.  You're also telling `getline` that `actionBuffer` can store 1024 values, but you only allocated 100.

Comment: `exit` is not a null-terminated string. Why didn't you write `char exit[] = "exit";`?

Comment: @paddy Thank you for the prompt response. So I would need to add a null character at the end of the **exit:** variable? Plus, I think I need to rename **exit** to something else.

Comment: Per your edit, your tutor/professor isn't "with it." You can't learn C++ by being taught C, and that has been the case since at least 2011. The whole idea of "to learn X you need to learn Y" only works when a principle is foundational to another; C and C++ sit alongside each other. Even so, you're code is riddled with issues per the other comments, and those are on you. Plenty of blame to go around.

Comment: probably not your fault, but if your tutor told you to not use C++, they should have told you what else to use and how. Telling students to stay away from `std::string` without explaining them that c-strings are nullterminated, is bs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to give you an idea, this would be an example of C++ code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string_view>
#include<string>
#include<sstream>
#include<exception>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::cout << "starting mvote...\n";

    //parse command line argumentand get the filename
    std::string filename = argv[2]; // NO CHECKS!
    std::cout << filename <<'\n';

    //from here, I'm opening the file and read it by lines
    {
        std::ifstream ifs(filename);
        if (!ifs) {
            throw std::invalid_argument("file not exists");
        }
        std::string line;
        while (std::getline(ifs, line)) {
            std::cout << line << '\n';
        }
    }

    bool run_flag = true;
    while (run_flag) {
        std::cout << "what do you want?\n";
        std::string userInput;
        std::getline(std::cin, userInput);
        if (userInput == "exit") {
            std::cout << "bye!\n";
            return 0;
        }
        std::stringstream userInputSs(userInput);
        std::string operation;
        while(userInputSs >> operation){
            std::cout << "operation: " << operation << '\n';
        }
    }
}
```